# Create new group in Odoo

Tags: odoo, usergroups

I want to create a new group for my custom module `Store` through the `Settings > Users > Groups` in odoo.

I am creating the group so that I can assign users to that `Store` module.

When i click on create, i need to write an `Application` name. I tried to write the name of my custom module which is `Store`. But, i am prompted to **create** one.

Should i be creating it? Or, did i get anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Groups, "Application" is category, if you will add it then it will createnew application under "Application Accesses" in users.

You will have all your groups under that category will display as selection in "Users" menu.